# Java Regex Matcher get wrong group count?

Tags: java, regex

My code is

```
String debug = "1$<$2";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^[1-5]" + "\\(?\\$[^\\$]*\\$\\)?" + "([1-5])$").matcher(debug);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
if (matcher.matches()) {
  for (var i = 0;i< matcher.groupCount();i++){
    matches.add(matcher.group(i));
  }
}
System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
System.out.println(matches);
```

And the group count is only 1.

The `matches` is `1$<$2`.

But actually the result of `matcher.group(1)` is `2`.

How can I get the right group count?

Comment: You have only one capturing group in your regex, `([1-5])` at the end.

Comment: Also note that `matcher.group(0)` will always be the full match. I.e. the input string. From the javadoc: *Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group()*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the first group (index 0) is the whole pattern and is not counted. See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount()):

> `public int groupCount()`

> Returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern.
> Group zero denotes the entire pattern by convention. It is not included in this count.
> Any non-negative integer smaller than or equal to the value returned by this method is guaranteed to be a valid group index for this matcher.

So you can change your code to this for example:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++){
  matches.add(matcher.group(i));
}
```